# How to restrict max rows selected to 25 in kogrid (multi selection enabled)

Tags: kogrid

I am trying to restrict the number of rows selected in kogrid to 25 as page size is more than 25 records. I tried implementing beforechange, but it didn't work for me.

Can anyone please help me on this?

Answer (score 0):

In general limiting a user while he selects rows is not a good idea. Try to warn user or block subsequent operations (like "Too many rows selected. Select not more than 25."). Write the warning in a kind of "status line". And don't try to block selection.